# Stop AngularJS untemplated request

Tags: angularjs

In my template I have something like the following:

```
<img data-ng-if="$ctrl.shouldShowFacebookPixel" 
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={{$ctrl.facebookPixelId}}&amp;ev=PageView"
 />
```

When I load the page I can see in my dev tools a request is made to

```
https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={{$ctrl.facebookPixelId}}&amp;ev=PageView
```

Then a bit later a request is made to the correct URL after the variable has been substituted.

```
https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=blah&amp;ev=PageView
```

How can I stop the initial request before variable substitution has happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for `ng-src` instead `src`:

```
<img data-ng-if="$ctrl.shouldShowFacebookPixel" 
  ng-src="{{'https://www.facebook.com/tr?id='+ $ctrl.facebookPixelId + '&amp;ev=PageView'}}"
 />
```

---

Angular needs to compile the URL, and your browser has no clue what is `{{/* ... */}}`. This is a reason why you see

```
https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={{$ctrl.facebookPixelId}}&amp;ev=PageView
```